# Подскажите название утилиты для Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, плагин, pylint

Подскажите название плагина, который выводит подобные подсказки.

Или как настроить Pycharm, чтобы Pylint выводил подсказки сразу в код?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насчет утилит для Pycharm пожалуйста уточните, что именно вы хотите узнать.